# Customising A Stubborn UL Element

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like li:first-child to be bold, which I have achieved but this affects the first element in my dropdown menu, in the navigation bar - under the header "Social". I would like only the first tab to be bold and everything else font-weight:normal. But I'm having a really difficult time in coding this effect. I have tried a few variations however to no avail. I have detailed the css coding :

```
#topdropnav li:first-child a {
font-weight: bold!important;
margin-left: 20px;
  }
```

The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [direct descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selector:

```
#topdropnav > ul > li:first-child a {
  font-weight: bold!important;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```